# scope in javascript.. parent scope variable not retaining value

Tags: javascript

I am a newbie to javascript..have gone thru multiple scope related blogs and several answers on stackoverflow..but not sure why this code doesnt work..

```
 function checkPhoneEmail(element, index, array) {
    var _contact = {};
    var _phone_empty = true;
    var _email_empty = true;
    var _phones_to_store = [];
    var _emails_to_store = [];
    var _prev_phone_number;
    var _phone;
    var i;
    //function to check if this phone 
    // should be included
    function checkMobilePhone(ph_element) {
        var _match;


        _match = ph_element.type.match(/mobile/i);
        if (_match && ph_element.value.length >= 10 && !(ph_element.value.match(/^800/) || ph_element.value.match(/^1800/) || ph_element.value.match(/^1-800/))) {
            return true;
        };
        return false;
    };

    if (!_.isEmpty(element.phoneNumbers)) {

        for (i = 0; i < element.phoneNumbers.length; i++) {
            console.log('prev num: ' + _prev_phone_number);
            console.log('curr num: ' + element.phoneNumbers[i].value)
            if (!_.isEqual(_prev_phone_number, element.phoneNumbers[i].value)) {
                if (checkMobilePhone(element.phoneNumbers[i])) {
                    _phone = {
                        id: element.phoneNumbers[i].id,
                        value: element.phoneNumbers[i].value
                    };
                    _phones_to_store.push(_phone);
                    console.log('phone to store: ' + element.phoneNumbers[i].value)
                };
            };
            _prev_phone_number = element.phoneNumbers[i].value;
            console.log('prev1 num: ' + _prev_phone_number);
        };

        _phone_empty = false;
    };

    if (!_.isEmpty(element.emails)) {

    };

};
```

why is the _prev_phone_number not being set ? I see it at prev1 num..but when you look for the next element its set back to undefined...my understanding is for doesnt create a new scope ? is this incorrect ?

I am trying to remove duplicates from phone contacts array (from cordova contacts) and doing some very basic checks to eliminate all numbers except a valid us mobile # for a mobile app..using above logic if a contact has multiple entries in contacts for same phone number i am seeing duplicates..Tried above logic with foreach and also _.uniq ... but same result..

Any help is appreciated.

sample Data:

```
{
    "id" : "1916",
    "rawId" : "1911",
    "displayName" : "John Doe",
    "name" : {
        "familyName" : "Doe",
        "formatted" : "John Doe",
        "givenName" : "John"
    },
    "nickname" : null,
    "phoneNumbers" : [{
            "type" : "mobile",
            "value" : "+1 999 666 9175",
            "id" : "11994",
            "pref" : false
        }, {
            "type" : "mobile",
            "value" : "+1 999 666 9175",
            "id" : "12001",
            "pref" : false
        }
    ],
    "emails" : null,
    "addresses" : null,
    "ims" : null,
    "organizations" : null,
    "birthday" : null,
    "note" : "",
    "photos" : null,
    "categories" : null,
    "urls" : null
}
```

Comment: can you please provide a jsfildde or plunker?

Comment: Can you provide input data? As mentioned before, working demo would be even better.

Comment: Provided sample data as edit to the orig question...@Shardul i apologize..but couldn't figure out how to get this working in jsfiddle..new to these tools.

Answer (score 0):

A for loop does not create its own scope. The issue is that you are trying to log to the console an undefined value.

```
for (i = 0; i < element.phoneNumbers.length; i++) {
        //_prev_phone_number is undefined here.
        console.log('prev num: ' + _prev_phone_number); 
        console.log('curr num: ' + element.phoneNumbers[i].value)
        if (!_.isEqual(_prev_phone_number, element.phoneNumbers[i].value)) {
            if (checkMobilePhone(element.phoneNumbers[i])) {
                _phone = {
                    id: element.phoneNumbers[i].id,
                    value: element.phoneNumbers[i].value
                };
                _phones_to_store.push(_phone);
                console.log('phone to store: ' + element.phoneNumbers[i].value)
            };
        };
        //This is the first time you have defined _prev_phone_number
        _prev_phone_number = element.phoneNumbers[i].value;
        console.log('prev1 num: ' + _prev_phone_number);
    };
```

You should probably check to see if `_prev_phone_number` has been defined before logging it to the console.

```
if(_prev_phone_number){
  console.log('prev num: ' + _prev_phone_number);
}
```

This would ensure that you are not logging an undefined value.

Comment: not sure if that is the issue..in the example data..i have two entries in phoneNumbers with the same exact telephone number .. named 'value' from cordova.  First iteration _prev_phone_number is 'undefined' which is correct...for the next iteration it _prev_phone_number still shows as undefined..
here is the output...
`rev num: undefined 
curr num: +1 999 666 9175
phone to store: +1 999 666 9175
prev1 num: +1 999 666 9175 
prev num: undefined 
curr num: +1 999 666 9175 
phone to store: +1 999 666 9175 
prev1 num: +1 999 666 9175 `

its sets of four..first iteration is first 4 rows and so on...

Comment: Here is additional input with Id included in output..hope its clear
-- First Iteration
prev num: undefined 
curr num: +1 999 666 9175 
phone to store: +1 999 666 9175 
prev1 num: +1 999 666 9175 
id: 12001 

-- Second Iteration
prev num: undefined 
curr num: +1 999 666 9175 
phone to store: +1 999 666 9175 
prev1 num: +1 999 666 9175 
id: 11994

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the variable `_prev_phone_number`, why don't you just access `element.phoneNumbers[i-1].value`? No need to introduce a new variable for it.

If that doesn't work, then something is clobbering your object and we will need to look deeper.

Comment: Folks, looks like the error was on my part...the contact that was giving error had two separate entries on the phone.  Since it was the same number it tripped me..I linked them manually and now there are no errors..
Thanks for the quick responses.  The sample data posted was from before they got unlinked..